# Excel VBA on Mac - Close Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos

The following code works 100% on PC but on Mac causes a popup message reading "There was a problem and Microsoft Excel was closed....." and an option to Recover work and restart Excel.

The when reopening the workbook you have to cancel several messages to open readonly...

How can I get the Mac to close without this happening...

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

I have tried all of the following:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:-True
```

They all produce the same result...

Comment: Unfortunately Excel for Mac is awfully put together. Mine crashes all the time and there's seemingly no real reason for it.

Comment: Thanks Callum,I learnt the hard way to keep things simple if you want compatibility with Apple MAC. However I never expected such a simple statement as this cause this much trouble...